# How to get the extent of a group of Raster layers and zoom to it with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I want to find a way to zoom to a group within the `QgsLayerTreeView`. The group only contains `QgsRasterLayer`. The indirect approach would be to create a `QgsRectangle` and serve it to the `QgsMapCanvas.setExtent()` method.

Unfortunately I don't see a way to obtain the extent of a `QgsRasterLayer`, kind of Bounding Box or "geometry", which I need for the creation of such a rectangle.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for but if you enable multiple layers in a group (or click the box beside the group name to enable/disable all group layers), you could use `canvas.zoomToFullExtent()` to zoom to the extent of all enabled layers.

Comment: Thanks. This would be the solution if there would be nothing else then this group layer. But there are also some additional Vector Layers outside of this group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea was actually fine. Raster layers' extent can be accessed via the `extent()` method. However, you would need to *combine* your rasters' extents before zooming in.

Assuming your raster layers and the map are in the same reference system (i.e., no on-the-fly projection), you can zoom in to the extent of a desired group copying this code snippet to your QGIS Python console:

```py
extent = QgsRectangle()
extent.setMinimal()

# Iterate through layers from certain group and combine their extent
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup("rasters") # Adjust this to fit your group's name
for child in group.children():
    if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
        extent.combineExtentWith( child.layer().extent() )

iface.mapCanvas().setExtent( extent )
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Please tell me if you face any trouble with it.

*Note: The solution above should work for both raster and vector layers.*

Comment: The solution worked fine for me. I finally did almost the same. I iterated trough all QgsRasterLayers and updated the `xMinimum()`, `xMaximum()`, `yMinimum()` and  `yMaximum()` of a QgsRectangle which I set as extent for the MapCanvas finally. Your way is more elegant.